# Add comma into text field for display value

Tags: javascript

I have a text field like this

The text field

[image]

The data is took from database, now I want to add comma into it every 3 digits, i want to solve it with jquery, is that possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7):

Solution1: you could simply use [Number.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```js
var number = 1557564534;
document.body.innerHTML = number.toLocaleString();
```

Solution 2: You could use regex to a make simple jquery plugin

```js
$.fn.digits = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
  })
}

$("span").digits();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="numbers">3456754323456432</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the jsfiddle for you to do inline formatting as you type. https://jsfiddle.net/wm61qzsm/

js code:

```
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    ;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the input to a float and use number.toLocalString();

```js
var data = $("#getInfo");
var dataParse = parseFloat(data.val());

dataParse = dataParse.toLocaleString();

$("#getInfoNew").val(dataParse);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
BEFORE<input type="text" id="getInfo" value="14000000,0"><br>
AFTER<input type="text" id="getInfoNew" value="">
```